# spring.sql.init.schema-locations Not Working

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, schema

I'm using profiles to determine which data connector to use (dev=h2, prod=mySQL).
I'm attempting to use

```
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=
```

To set the location to the relevant path with properties from the active profile but I keep getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No schema scripts found at location './database/h2/schema-h2.sql'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
```

and the same error no matter where I point the property to.

Is there any other special syntax for declaring which file or which directory under resources for this property?  When I edit this property autocomplete in Idea happily shows the folder/file structure, but Spring can't see what I'm pointing to!

Comment: Have you tried configuring it with a `file:` or `classpath:` prefix? You probably want the latter as that will allow the file to be loaded from within a jar once you’ve packaged your application for deployment. The script should then be placed beneath `src/main/resources`.

Comment: adding classpath: seems to have fixed it!
Thank you!
If you provide that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer as per @Andy Wilkinson's comment above:

Adding classpath: as a prefix resolved the issue.

Comment: No luck for me for dataLocation, how can we fix it in Spring Boot App?